# Attribute Error : 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schemaString="Address_Type,Address_ID,Address_Line_1,Address_Line_2,Address_Line_3,City,County,Zip,State,Country,Dflt_Address_Ind,Row_Insert_TS,Row_Update_TS,SYS_CHANGE_VERSION,SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION"

fields=schemaString.split(",").map(lambda fieldName: StructField(fieldName, StringType(), nullable = true))

schema = StructType(fields)
```

When I am using the above code I am getting this error:

```
Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: well, a list object doesn't have a `map` attribute... You probably mean `map(lambda fieldname: ... , schemaString.split(","))`. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is a built-in **function**, not a list method

Comment: I used the below code as per your suggestion , fields= map(lambda fieldName: StructField(fieldName, StringType()) , schemaString.split(",")) ,   schema = StructType(fields)  I am getting output StructType(List())

Comment: Please note that `map` returns a mapping object, if you need a list you must do `list(map(...))`. You might also just use list-comprehension as suggested in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List does not have map attribute. You can try something like this to achieve what you are trying to do

```
fields=[StructField(fieldName, StringType(), nullable = True) for fieldName in schemaString.split(",")]
```

Comment: Thank you moham it is working, is there any possibility to work with map method, because for the performance perspective map execute fast compared to looping

Comment: For generating structure, map is completely unnecessary and you won't find any performance changes. For RDD / dataframe, map would perform better because the values are distributed and for each set of values, map will happen simultaneously. Here, your source is constant. So it is not required. 

You can only use python's inbuilt function map for list. LIke this fields=map(lambda x:StructField(x,StringType(),True),SchemaString) but as I said there won't be any performance improvements.


Kindly consider accepting my answer if it works for you